# New Button is not registering as pressed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

## Problem

### Description:

There is a problem with the following code. The new button in this  division is not actually be pressed or anything when I click on it. I do not understand why. I had already place a console.log() to test if it would output anything showing me successful registry of the press. However, even then it never gets print to log. This is for the demographics-button-new class.

## Demographics Modal Code

```
        {showDemographicsDetails && (
          <div className="demographics-overlay" onClick={() => setShowDemographicsDetails(false)}>
              <div className="demographics-details" onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
                  <div className="demographics-title">
                    <span>Demographics Details</span>
                  </div>
                  <ul>
                      <li>Duty Status: {dutyStatus}</li>
                      <li>Age: {age}</li>
                      <li>Marital Status: {maritalStatus}</li>
                      <li>Grade: {grade}</li>
                      <li>Sex: {sex}</li>
                      <li>Handedness: {handedness}</li>
                      <li>Height: {height}</li>
                      <li>Weight: {weight}</li>
                      <li>Military Occupational Speciality: {militaryOccupationalSpeciality}</li>
                      <li>Amount of Siblings: {siblingsCount}</li>
                  </ul>
                  <div>
                    {/* Direct alert on the button to test if it's being clicked */}
                    <button className="demographics-button-new" style={{ border: '2px solid red' }} onClick={() => 
                        handleNewDemographicButtonClick()
                    }>
                        New
                    </button>
                    <button className="demographics-button-edit" onClick={() => setShowEditModal(true)}>Edit</button>
                    <button className="demographics-button-save" onClick={handleSaveDetailsButton}>Save</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          )}
```

And here is the related handler for handleNewDemographicButtonClick():

```
const handleNewDemographicButtonClick = () => {
  console.log("New Button was Clicked!");
  alert("Button Clicked!");
  setShowNewDemographicModal(true);
};
```

Comment: Are you using a framework of some kind? `onClick={() => handleNewDemographicButtonClick()}` is not correct HTML.

Comment: In HTML you write `onclick="handleNewDemographicButtonClick()"`

Comment: it may be related to your stop propagation code. You have outer divs with click events on them and then buttons inside those divs with more click events.

Comment: This looks like React? Your button and function work fine by themselves in React, I just tested. I'd check your console to see if there are any errors that may be preventing your onClick. Also check to see if the parent element onClicks are being triggered somehow (CSS could cause them to sit on top of your button).

Comment: @Barmar im using REACTJS

Comment: Your code seems to work fine here's a [working example](https://3f24yw.csb.app/) . I think the problem might be with CSS ( like pointer-events : none  ? ) Can you share your CSS too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was merely a file name error. Everything included works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).